# django adding a background image to admin site

Tags: css, django, admin

I need to display a background image in the Django admin site. I have looked to all questions but none of the solutions seems to work for me.
I just want the background to appear in the back of the admin site.
I have a base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block extrastyle %}

{{ block.super }}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/admin-extra.css" %}" />
{%endblock%}
```

The extra-admin.css

```
  head.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('{{ STATIC_URL }} background.png') ;

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

This extra-admin.css is loaded as I see it in the Firefox inspector. However, the image does not appear. something seems to appear in the background but is immediately covered by the normal admin site with white background.

Comment: try to add `background-image: url('{{ STATIC_URL }} background.png') !important`, maybe you need this due to wrong selector.

Comment: I did add !importnt. Does not change anything.

Comment: `head.bg` - is this a correct selector? maybe `.` or `#` is lost in front of it (I'm not familiar with admin pages struct)?

Comment: I am new to web development. I just discovered that the admin-extra.css is  not loaded. I have in the console an error code :   "GET /static/css/admin-extra.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1681.   this means that the css is not loaded.  Therefor it would be a django static file path problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution`. Here is base_site.html

```
{% load static %}    
{% block extrastyle %}     
{{ block.super }}    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/admin_extra.css' %}"    />
{%endblock%}
```

here is admin-extra.css

```
body {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('background.png') !important;
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

settings.py is

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "E6000_stitch_techniques", "static"),
)     
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Make sure to look into the django console to catch all errors 404 when a static file cnnot be served.

Answer (score 0):

Add a directory to your static folder:

```
/static/admin/css
```

and inside this directory copy from your site_packages the admin's base.css.

```
base.css
```

Try overriding base.css and set the body's background-image. Also delete background: #fff;.

Comment: How do I override bse.css? This is exactly what I am trying to do!....Shoul I just delete it from the admin repository?

Comment: How do I override base.css. Should I just delete it in the admin directory? This is rather violent!...

Comment: @piscvau - No you don't need to delete anything. Simply add an admin folder inside your static directory, and inside add a css folder, just like the admin static in your site_packages. Then you can just copy base.css to here, change it how you want it, and it will take effect.